# Angular js: Load Unity Web Export from Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-applications, unity-game-engine

my name is Juan Camilo Guarin P. and i have been working on a project i have, where i need to load from angularjs a unity3d file, using the Unity web exported html.

Here is the thing, Unity 3d loads the content through jquery, but even if i have already included it to my html file, i can't get my content loaded properly.

Here I include both the script and the html Unity 3d exports by default:

First the script:

```
    var unityObjectUrl = "http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js";
    if (document.location.protocol == 'https:')
    unityObjectUrl = unityObjectUrl.replace("http://", "https://ssl-");
    document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + unityObjectUrl + '"><\/script>');

    var config = {
        width: $(window).width() / 1.2,
        height: $(window).height() / 1.2,
        params: {enableDebugging: "0"}
        };
    var u = new UnityObject2(config);
    jQuery(function() {
           var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
           var $brokenScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".broken");
           $missingScreen.hide();
           $brokenScreen.hide();
           u.observeProgress(function(progress) {
                    switch (progress.pluginStatus) {
                           case "broken":
                                 $brokenScreen.find("a").click(function(e) {
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                            u.installPlugin();
                                        return false;
                                        });
                                 $brokenScreen.show();
                                 break;
                           case "missing":
                                 $missingScreen.find("a").click(function(e) {
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        u.installPlugin();
                                        return false;
                                        });
                                 $missingScreen.show();
                                 break;
                           case "installed":
                                 $missingScreen.remove();
                                 break;
                           case "first":
                                 break;
                      }
            });
    u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "recorridovirtual.unity3d");
                                });
```

This script is between script tags in the html file. Now this is the html that works:

```
<div id="unityPlayer">
            <div class="missing">
                <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                    <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="broken">
                <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install.">
                    <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install." src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunityrestart.png" width="193" height="63" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in the head it includes:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ssl-webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Now, what do i want to do?

I want to load the .unity3d file and change it's name dynamically to the html using angular js.

This all happens because, also, i don't know how to include, or use, a variable i define in a controller on angular js on a template script. If I knew, it would be very easy to just replace the name of the unity3d file and so load a different one, but as far as i have searched i haven't seen any answer to that question and now i'm trying to do all this process on an angular way.

I would be very grateful if you can answer my question,

Thank you so much to all of you, and i know there should be other people with the same doubt.

Juan Camilo Guarin P.

Comment: Your name is not relevant, no need to be overly polite either. In fact it's best to open straight with the problem summary, then the facts & code, and a question. No thanks, signature or anything else needed. SO users are pragmatic to their very core. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm asking a question and i see no response yet. NO need to be correcting my usage of the platform as long as the question is understandable

Comment: It does deter from reading the question if you write it like an email, which in turn reduces the likelihood of getting an answer.